# python : list structure for input of pyti average true range function

Tags: python, python-3.x, trading

I'm new to Python and I would like to use the average_true_range() function of pyti. ATR is based on True Range ( https://github.com/kylejusticemagnuson/pyti/blob/master/pyti/true_range.py ), but I have a hard time understanding how the input for True Range should look like.

True Range is calculated with the high, low and last close ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_true_range )

True Range is calculated this way in pyti:

```
tr = [np.max([np.max(close_data[idx+1-period:idx+1]) -
                np.min(close_data[idx+1-period:idx+1]),
                abs(np.max(close_data[idx+1-period:idx+1]) -
                close_data[idx-1]),
                abs(np.min(close_data[idx+1-period:idx+1]) -
                close_data[idx-1])]) for idx in range(period-1, len(close_data))]
    tr = fill_for_noncomputable_vals(close_data, tr)
```

This means:

high value of the day is collected via np.max(close_data[idx+1-period:idx+1])

low value of the day is collected via np.min(close_data[idx+1-period:idx+1])

close of the previous day is collected via close_data[idx-1]

How should I populate close_data[] in order to get this working?
Something like this?:

```
close_data=[high day1, low day1, close day1,
            high day2, low day2, close day2, etc...]
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass in `close_data = [close_day1, close_day2, close_day3, ...]` and `period = index_between_0_and_len_of_close_data`.

I.e. for close_data you just pass values of all closing prices. And for period you pass just index, any integer number between 0 and len(close_data) (non-inclusive).

You may also look into [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_true_range) about average true range and true range.

Comment: That is indeed what I initially did, but I get incorrect results. The Wikipedia page mentions that TR is based on high and low as well, so why don't they have to passed?

Comment: @Greggy Basically that answer I came up was after I looked into code of `true_range.py`, basically it just iterates in double loop through all values, it means that it doesn't differentiate between types of values, all values are the same. Regarding High and Low - that `true_range.py` computes this high and low next way - e.g. if you have 365 days data, this code computes maximum of 365 days closing prices and minimum for the whole year. That is were High and Low come from, they are just computed.

Comment: @Greggy So High and Low don't refer to high and low of each day, they refer to global max and min for whole period.